# Not able to delete renderable in Arcore using anchornodes

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I have tried my best to remove the renderable but the renderable is not getting vanished after i click on the button. I had taken help of the stackoverflow similiar post but i was not able to delete the renderable even after applying the following code.
I am using virtual device for testing.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(anchorNode!=null){
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(anchorNode);
            anchorNode.getAnchor().detach();
            anchorNode.setParent(null);
            anchorNode = null;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Delete - anchorNode removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Delete - markAnchorNode was null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Please tell me a solution for this

Comment: I think this is the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54179660/334402 and it has been tested and works, although this is just an extract. The complete project is available here so testing with this may help you find the issue: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `Node` on which you have used a `setRenderable()`, 
[In this case]
Make sure you are rendering a `Renderable` on the `anchorNode` object.